# Matlab.Compute $f(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)-1$

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Write a procedure to compute $f(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x) - 1$

The routine should produce nearly full machine precision for all $x$ in the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$

*Hint:* $\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1}{2} (1-\cos2\theta)$

I don't really understand why we need to do any kind of substitution to avoid
uncertainty. There might be some values on the interval $[0, \pi/4]$ that make $\sin x + \cos x$ be approximately equal to $1$?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right. When $x$ is very close to $0$, $\sin x + \cos x$ is very close to $1$, so subtracting $1$ would potentially lose several digits of precision.

Comment: so do I substitute my original expression with $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (1-\cos 2 x)} + \cos x -1$?

Comment: That wouldn't help much, since at the end of the day, for small $x$, you're still subtracting two nearly equal numbers. I must admit I do not know the answer for this one, but I would rather attempt to substitute the $1$ for $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnLennon: no, you substitute $\cos x - 1$ by $-2 \sin^2(x/2)$. The cancellation between $\cos x - 1$ is the main culprit when $x \ll 1$. Replacing it by $\sin^2(x/2)$ helps you retain precision, so long as the computation of $\sin$ is precise.